# Complex SQL where clause with multiple AND and OR condition

Tags: mysql, oracle, where-clause

I am trying something like this

```
Where (((t1.column1=value1 and t1.column2=value1) OR 
        (t1.column1=value2 and t1.column2=value2)) 
   AND ((t1.column1=value3 and t1.column2=value3) OR 
        (t1.column1=value4 and t1.column2=value4) OR 
       (...)))
```

When i execute the first part of the query with 'OR' condition executes and returns the resultset. If i include the second part of the query starting with 'AND' result set returned is 0.

Can someone pls help where i am going wrong. Thanks

modified query for better understanding

```
 WHERE (    (   (    dataType = 'int'     AND DATA = '1')
             OR (    dataType = 'Integer' AND DATA = '1')
            )
        AND (   (    dataType = 'String' AND DATA = '17890')
             OR (    dataType = 'String' AND DATA = '178postal')
            )
       )
```

Comment: ... you're asking for `t1.column1` to be at least two different values simultaneously. How do you expect any rows to match that?

Comment: T1.Column1 can't be value1 and value3 for the same record  (assuming values 1 and 3 are actually different)

Comment: After the modification for better understanding: You are requiring datatype to be 'int' or 'Integer' and ALSO to be 'String' as well. Does that make sense to you? Should you get anything other than the empty set from this query?

Comment: Perhaps you meant "AND" to be "OR" instead?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're saying that t1.column1 needs to be either value1 or value2 and t1.column1 needs to be either value3 or value4 at the same time.

Unless value1 and value3 can be the same at the same time, then how is that make sense ?
I think you've got some errors in your logic.